# Angular / Ionic - controller only runs once

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm starting out with Angular through the Ionic Framework but I am failing to understand why the controller only runs once i.e. I change state, the controller runs, change to another state and then back again and the controller does not run a second time. This is my state:

```
$stateProvider.state( 'container.previous', {
    url: 'previous',
    views: {
        main : {
            templateUrl : 'views/previous.html',
            controller : function( $scope, $cordovaSQLite ){
                $scope.firms = [];
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(window.db, "SELECT * FROM recent GROUP BY phone ORDER by id DESC").then(function(res) {
                    for (i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                        $scope.firms.push(res.rows.item(i));
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            }
        }
    },
    onStateChangeStart : function(){
        backButton = true;

    }
});
```

In another state, if you click on a button related to a "firm", it saves the "firms" data to local storage. The above state shows the firms in which you have previously clicked on. But I cannot figure out how to update the `$scope.firms` correctly as the controller never runs again.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can put the code you want to run in $ionicView.enter:

```
controller : function( $scope, $cordovaSQLite ){
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        // code to run each time view is entered
    });

    ...
});
```

See "View LifeCycle and Events": https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 5):

Building on @brandyshea's answer, I would like to add if you want to specify no caching in one area/controller/state, and take advantage of the caching in other areas, you can simply use the `cache` parameter in your `$stateProvider` for that state.

> Disable cache within state provider
>
> ```
> $stateProvider.state('myState', {
>   cache: false,
>   url : '/myUrl',
>   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
> })
> ```

Alternatively, you can use one of the other methods too:

> Disable cache with an attribute
>
> ```
> <ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
> ...
> </ion-view>
> ```
>
> Disable cache globally
>   The $ionicConfigProvider can be used to set the maximum allowable views which can be cached, but this can also be use to disable all caching by setting it to 0.
>
> ```
> $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
> ```

References: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/ and http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to disable entire app cache.
If you want to re-run controller every time you enter on it you should clear cache before you leave it:

```
 $scope.$on("$ionicView.afterLeave", function () {
         $ionicHistory.clearCache();
 });
```

Comment: Quick question, this clears all the cache, can you clear the cache for that one state?

Comment: I think clear cache dinamically for only one state is not possible yet. you can configure your state to not be cached but that way that state will never be cached

Answer (score 2):

Ionic has a cache mechanism inside. You can disable caching globally in your config function like this :

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your ion-view.

```html
<ion-view cache-view="false">
```