# How to run controller each time angularjs ui-router named view is activated?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

In regular angularjs ui-router state the controller runs each time the state is activated. I found this not to be the case when dealing with named views in an ionic application. The named view controller runs only once per element(game). Eg. user displays a game -> controller runs. Then user goes to another state and upon their return to displaying the same game controller does not run again - the view uses an already generated scope from before. I would like reinitialise that games scope with controller.

My code:

```
//app.js
.state('app.game', {
  url: "/x/{gameID:int}",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/html/my-game.html",
      controller: 'GameCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

...

```
//controllers.js
controllers.controller('GameCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Game) {
  //alert("running controller");
  Game.get({id: $stateParams.gameID}, function(res){
    $scope.game = res;
  }); 
})
```

Edit: I actually use this code to go to the view of game (currently  playing with guid idea from Steven Wexler)

```
<ion-view view-title="Games">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Games</h1>
    <ion-list>
    <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/x/{{game.id}}?guid=    {{guid()}}" ng-repeat="game in games">
        {{game.id}}
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>    
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Think your problem is already solved in this post [Angular / Ionic - controller only runs once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273737/angular-ionic-controller-only-runs-once)
[brandyshea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3802466/brandyshea) says that you need to add the code you want to run in the `$ionicView.enter` event

```
controller : function( $scope, $cordovaSQLite ){
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        // code to run each time view is entered
    });

    ...
});
```

Comment: this seems to be what I am looking for. I will update you soon.

Comment: Remember to tell i this is works fine and if you can mark this answer as useful please

Comment: Ok, so the other stackoverflow question was about this exactly issue(my bad!). Your answer seems to be proper one but what worked best for me was adding 'cache: false' to app.game state. More in documentation linked from the other question. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are navigating to a state with the same url and params that was previously loaded.  One way to force a reload is to pass in a guid as a parameter with your state and set `reloadOnSearch=true` (it's true by default).  The second way to force a reload is to use the reload option added in version 0.2.5.

**Option 1**

```
.state('app.game', {
  url: "/x/{gameID:int}/{guid}",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/html/my-game.html",
      controller: 'GameCtrl'
    }
  }
})

$state.go("app.game", { gameId: id, guid: guid }); 

function guid() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}
```

**Option 2 (if you have version >= 0.2.5)**

```
.state('app.game', {
  url: "/x/{gameID:int}",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/html/my-game.html",
      controller: 'GameCtrl'
    }
  },
  reload: true
})
```

*Note: Awesome guid function copied from [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)*

Comment: sorry, I can not upvote you cause my low rep. I went with more ionic specific solution but this one seems to be very good quality. Thx